# Test each case/return using Jest/ Enzyme

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Trying to test the following using jest and Enzyme. When I run npm-coverage, it shows that each case has not being tested. Not really sure how to approach a solution

Here is the code

```
renderColumnDropdown = () => {
if (this.props.columnIdList != undefined) {
let columnOptions = Object.keys(this.props.columnIdList).map(key => {
  switch (key) {
    case 'sort':
      return false
    case 'filters':
      return false
    case 'group':
      return false
    case 'dimensions':
      return false
    case 'pivot':
      return false
    case 'pivotanalysis':
      return false
    default:
    return (
      <option value={key} key={key}>{this.props.columnIdList[key]}</option>
    )
  }
})
```

This is how I usually set up my test cases: Using shallow

```
it('Test renderColumnDropdown function',() => {
  wrapper.setProps({
    columnIdList:[{
        key:'pivotanalysis'
        }],
    })
  wrapper.setState({
     }),
  wrapper.update();
  expect(wrapper.instance().renderColumnDropdown({defaultData:{filters:[{ column:''}]}})).toBeDefined();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor your code by combining all cases in one which are returning same value to get them covered, and it should have first key to cover all branches.

```
switch (key) {
    case 'sort':
    case 'filters':
    case 'group':
    case 'dimensions':
    case 'pivot':
    case 'pivotanalysis':
        return false
    default: 
        return (
            <option value={key} key={key}>{this.props.columnIdList[key]}</option>
        )
```